# What is the Best way to Expose Data from an AWS RDS Mysql DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I currently have a mysql database on AWS RDS.

I am in need of accessing and looking up information on a daily basis of the data in that database via an external CRM.

In an ideal scenario, I could create an API on Lambda that would have access to the RDS instance and have that be my front facing API that my CRM API could hit up and lookup and work with my mysql data.

My question is... is this the best way to do it? Is there some sort of service out there that facilitates me creating an API or do I need to create an API from scratch...

Any suggestions? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You can use the [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/getting-started/) There's a good getting started guide for using [Lambda Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html). But I expect you know this as you've tagged your question with aws-api-gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create your own AWS Lambda app, but there is a framework - the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) which will make the whole endeavour much easier!

This [Tutorial on Accessing RDS from AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html) might help as well.